# Substitute string of variable in bash file

Tags: bash

I have bash file example.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=''
# if VAR empty - run this
if [-z "${VAR}" ]; then
  # some complex formula for VAR. Output is string.
   VAR = 'blablabla'
fi
```

I need in next run:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR='blablabla'
# if VAR empty - run this
if [-z "${VAR}" ]; then
  # some complex formula for VAR. Output is string.
   VAR = 'blablabla'
fi
```

VAR varable in next run in example.sh file is defined as 'blablabla'. How i can do this?

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors. Can we assume that you don't need help with that part, and that we can correctly guess which part you do need help with?

Comment: In the meantime, setting `VAR` to the desired value in the calling shell is probably a more robust and fruitful approach.

Comment: I need calculate and write in script new 'VAR' if 'VAR' is not defined. In next run (in n hours) script will run with this 'VAR'. How i can place calculated 'VAR' in variable for next script run?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend passing in `VAR` as an input argument.

You can then recursively call your script within itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=$1
# if VAR empty - run this
if [ -z "${VAR}" ]; then
    # some complex formula for VAR. Output is string.
    VAR='blablabla'
    $0 $VAR    # recursively call script with new VAR
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to export `VAR`. New iteration of script, started as subshell, will not see the set value...

Comment: It doesn't need to be exported if it is passed as a command-line argument. It should properly be double-quoted, though.

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=
FULL_PATH_TO_SCRIPT = $( readlink -m $( type -p $0 ))
# if VAR empty - run this
if [-z "${VAR}" ]; then
    # some complex formula for VAR. Output is string.
    VAR = blablabla
    sed -i '0, /VAR=/s//VAR='${VAR}'/' $FULL_PATH_TO_SCRIPT
fi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify the script itself. Write the necessary value of `VAR` to an external file, and read from that file when the script starts.

```
var_file=/var/lib/myscript/var   # Just an example; put the file where convenient
read VAR < "$var_file"
# Compute value of VAR for next time
echo "$VAR" > "$var_file"
```